# How to move a PCs Debian to a USB and remain fully bootable?

Tags: debian, usb-drive, bootable, cloning

I have a 64 GB USB 3.0 drive, to which I'd like to transfer (in terms of file system and grub2 bootability) the Debian Jessie installed on the SSD of my retina MacBook Pro.

I am looking to do this in as few steps as possible, and for the result to be a seamless working bootable USB that boots up the exact same Debian install with my Icedove mail folders, customised settings, Nautilus tweaks, etc.

What is the most convenient way to do this?

Lastly, I have cryptsetup installed as it's a LUKS-encrypted LVM, not sure how that would complicate things. Other than that, no propietary drivers, everything as free and simple as possible. amd64.